# How can I change the ordering of levels for a categorical SpatRaster in terra?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, terra

I have two rasters and I would like them to have the same levels and in the same order. However, one of the rasters does not have all the levels that the other does but I have managed to add these levels in using `levels(rast) <- all_labels`.

My issue is that now the two RATs have all the same levels (even though some of the levels are not seen in one of the actual rasters), but the levels are in different orders, and therefore, the same label is associated with a different integer:

E.g.

```
#Showing the first 5 of each to illustrate the issue
#original raster
[[1]]
   ID                                   label
1   0                                   Ocean
2   1                         Urban Ecosystem
3   2                             Bare Ground
4   3                       Coastal Ecosystem
5   4                        Alpine Ecosystem
...

#New raster
   ID                                   label
1   0                             Bare Ground
2   1                         Urban Ecosystem
3   2                       Coastal Ecosystem
4   3                                   Ocean
5   4                        Alpine Ecosystem
...
```

So, what I would like to do is have the labels correspond to the same integer. If this were a base R problem I would use `factor(..., levels = c(...))` to simply change the ordering of the labels, which would update the underlying integers in the dataframe accordingly.

e.g.

```
#Creating a factor which has the levels in alphabetical order
incorrect_factor <- factor(c(one, two, three, four))
incorrect_factor

#Changing ordering
factor_reordered <- factor(my_factor, levels = c("one", "two", "three", "four"))
factor_reordered
```

Is there a way to do the same kind of thing with `terra`? I think I can see a way to do it with `terra::classify` to change the actual integers; essentially manually re-classifying the underlying integers in the problem raster to match my target raster but I am not certain it would work and it would make for a very error prone bit of code...

Below is some code that I pulled from examples to create a categorical raster to create a small reprex of the problem:

```
#Creating a raster (using the terra::cats example code)
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

cls <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"))
levels(r) <- cls

#Original
plot(r)
levels(r)

#Second raster with variables in a different order - this would be the one to change to match the above raster with the labels in the same order and the integers updated to reflect this.
r_2 <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r_2) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

cls <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("water", "urban","forest"))
levels(r_2) <- cls
plot(r_2)
levels(r_2)
```

I have googled this quite a bit and I haven't found any thing that addresses the issue I am having but if I missed anything please let me know!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, I've been in a similar situation before but can't get to the laptop to test and write my solution that I applied then. so here's an interactive way to do it if your data is not very large, install "questionr" package, then from "Add-ins" in r studio you will find factor recoding and factor reordering. Drag and drop your desired ordered, and you'll get the right code to copy and paste. Let me know if it works with you.

Comment: It would be much better to only use the repex to ask your question. The specifics or your real data do not matter.

Comment: Noted for next time @RobertHijmans - I just thought it would more clearly demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a method for this, but it is not that hard to do this "manually". Note that I am using terra version 1.5.44, which is currently the development version. You can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

Example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.5.44
set.seed(0)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
levels(r) <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("forest", "water", "urban"))
  
r_2 <- setValues(r, sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE))
levels(r_2) <- data.frame(id=1:3, cover=c("water", "urban","forest"))
 
levels(r)[[1]]
#  id  cover
#1  1 forest
#2  2  water
#3  3  urban
levels(r_2)[[1]]
#  id  cover
#1  1  water
#2  2  urban
#3  3 forest
```

Solution

First merge the labels and their codes

```
m <- merge(levels(r)[[1]], levels(r_2)[[1]], by=2, all=TRUE)
m
#   cover id.x id.y
#1 forest    1    3
#2  urban    3    2
#3  water    2    1

# for labels that do not occur in the first raster
# not relevant in this example
m <- m[!is.na(m[,2]), ]
```

Use `subst` and set the new levels

```
s <- subst(r_2, m[,3], m[,2])
levels(s) <- levels(r)
 
levels(s)[[1]]
#  id  cover
#1  1 forest
#2  2  water
#3  3  urban
```

Comment: Example not working. m <- merge(levels(r)[[1]], levels(r_2)[[1]], by=2, all=TRUE)
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns

Comment: For me, merge doesn't work because > levels(r)[[1]]
[1] "forest" "water"  "urban"

Comment: I added code to be able to replicate m. The results for levels(s)[[1]] produce the same output as your example, but plot(s) shows a raster with only one level, urban, and the other two classes don't show up. It does not look like a re-leveld version of r_2

Comment: I'm using terra 1.5-34, could this be why? seems reasonable to make the example using the CRAN version of the package IMO

Comment: As you can see I am using a later version; I should have mentioned that. You can install it with `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`  --- as this answer will stay on this site, I prefer to look forward. With older versions you can use `cats` instead of `levels` (but that may break if there are multiple attributes); but `subst` also works a bit differently there.

Answer (score 1):

The principles in Robert Hijman's example worked for me, but the code of the example didn't. Here's an example that I got to work.

```
#sample data from the subst help file
z <- rast(ncols=5, nrows=5, xmin=0, xmax=1, ymin=0, ymax=1, crs="")
z <- init(z, 1:6)
x <- subst(z, 3, 7)
x <- subst(z, 2:3, NA)
x <- subst(x, NA, 10)

levels(x) <- data.frame(value = c(1,4,5,6,10),
                        lc_class = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))



#idenfity what t0 want to change the values to 
new_levels <- data.frame(new_value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                          old_value  = c(1,4,5,6,10, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                         lc_class = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"))

#substitute new values for old values
y <- subst(x, new_levels$old_value, new_levels$new_value)

#rename levels according to new values
levels(y) <- new_levels[,c(1,3)]

#add a cell from one of the new levels to test that it worked and plots properly
y[1,1] <- 10
plot(y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help canderson! I have marked Robert's as the answer since I have been working off of the development version and it will probably be the one that holds true going forward.